# learning how to read data from MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to learn php and mysql, I was trying to read data from my database where i was following something online and encounter an error(s) here is my code

```
<?php
  include 'includes/conn.php';

   $query =sprintf("Select * from customer");
   $result = mysql_query($query);

   if (!$result) 
   {
   $message  ='from you see this then it's not connecting!'.mysql_error() ."\n";
      $message .= 'everything' .$query;
      die($message);
   }   

    while ($customer = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
       echo $row['cust_id'];
       echo $row['fname'];
       echo $row['lname'];
       echo $row['gender'];
       echo $row['dob'];
    }
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

//this is where i was trying to make a connection with the database

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';

$db ='telmar_php';
$con = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
mysql_select_db($db);
?>
```

Comment: First error is here `$message  ='from you see this then it's not connecting!'.mysql_error() ."\n";`

Comment: "and encounter an error(s)" - so _what_ error did you encounter? Do you want us to _guess_? Tell us!

Comment: don't use *mysql_*-functions, then to debug youself $con = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass) or die(mysql_error()); etc ... exampels you find on php.net

Comment: Use IDE with code highlighting

Answer (score 0):

**Replace**

```
$message  ='from you see this then it's not connecting!'.mysql_error() ."\n";
```

here your string is  single quotation marks in  `it's` is causing the problem

**with**

```
$message  ="from you see this then it's not connecting!".mysql_error() ."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

...and to display your results change this:

```
while ($customer = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
```

to this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please review the below example for reading data my mysql using php.    

$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";

}
```